# How to check multiple GET if equals a string?

Tags: php

in this php code, i'm trying to check if one of those requests isset and if one of them value == 'x', but the function always output "selected" on all options, what i'm doing wrong?

**Function:**

```
function getSortBy(){
    
        if (isset($_GET['sortby']) && !empty($_GET['sortby'])) {
            
            if ($_GET['sortby'] == 'default') {
                return 'selected';
            }elseif($_GET['sortby'] == 'price-desc'){
                return 'selected';
            }elseif($_GET['sortby'] == 'price-asc'){
                return 'selected';
            }elseif($_GET['sortby'] == 'date-desc'){
                return 'selected';
            }elseif($_GET['sortby'] == 'date-asc'){
                return 'selected';
            }elseif($_GET['sortby'] == 'size-desc'){
                return 'selected';
            }elseif($_GET['sortby'] == 'size-asc'){
                return 'selected';
            }else{
                return null;
            }
    
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Html:**

```
<select>
<option value="default" <?php echo getSortBy(); ?>>Default</option>
<option value="price-desc" <?php echo getSortBy(); ?>>Price High to Low</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The way you coded it will always return `selected`. What are you expecting to print.  Lets say if $_GET['sortby'] == 'price-desc' what do you want to print in your HTML?

Comment: Your function says that when _any_ of those values are true, then it returns selected. You probably want to pass into that function the value, e.g. `<?php echo getSortBy('price-desc'); ?>` and in your function just check `if ($_GET['sortby'] == $valPassedIntoFunction) { return 'selected'; }` or similar.

Comment: Don't forget that you need to add a name attribute to your select element.  There is no 'sortby' name attribute and hence no key in $_GET for your given example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to compare the value of `$_GET['sortby']` with the value of the options, otherwise if `$_GET['sortby']` has any of those values, all option elements will have attribute `selected`.

PHP:

```
function getSortBy($value){ 
   if (isset($_GET['sortby']) && !empty($_GET['sortby'])) {
      if ($_GET['sortby'] == $value) {
          return 'selected';
      } else {
          return null;
      } 
   } else {
      return null;
   }
}
```

HTML:

```
<select>
<option value="default" <?php echo getSortBy('default'); ?>>Default</option>
// ect.
<option value="price-desc" <?php echo getSortBy('price-desc'); ?>>Price High to Low</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

It works with PHP 7.3.

File: test_html1.php

Source:

```
<?php
$options = [
    'default' => 'Default',
    'price-desc' => 'Price High to Low',
];
$currVal = isset($_GET['sortby']) ? $_GET['sortby'] : '';
?>
<html>
<form>
    <select name="sortby">
        <?php foreach ($options as $val => $name) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $val; ?>" <?php if ($currVal == $val) echo ' selected="selected"' ?>>
                <?php echo $name; ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
</html>
```

Put it on server for test, such as http://localhost/test_html1.php.

Answer (score 1):

Short and simple:

```
<select>
    <option value="default" <?= markSelected('default') ?>>Default</option>
    <option value="price-desc" <?= markSelected('price-desc') ?>>Price High to Low</option>
</select>
<?php

function markSelected($value)
{
    if ($_GET['sortby'] ?? null === $value)
    {
        return 'selected';
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
function getSortBy ($value)
{
     if (isset($_GET['sortby']) && $_GET['sortby'] === $value) {
         return "value = '$value' selected ";
     }

     return "value = '$value' ";
}
```

HTML:

```
<select>
<option <?= getSortBy('default') ?>>Default</option>
<option <?= getSortBy('price-desc') ?>>Price High to Low</option>
</select>
```